# How to auto sum upwards until no number is found?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to make a cell auto calculate all numbers above until there is no number (in my example until it meets merged cell "TEXT ROW").

For better understanding there is screenshot: https://prnt.sc/7p8fPagzt3Ep

So far I've made cell E8 to count up until given cell E2: `=SUM(E2:INDEX(E:E;ROW()-1))`
The problem is that I have to write E2 in formula. Is there any way to make formula auto stop at E2?

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work for you:

`=SUM(indirect("E"&row()-counta(A2:A)&":E"&ROW()-1))`

By using `row()-counta(A2:A)`, I am taking the row that the formula is in, and subtracting the number of data entries starting at A2 (ie ignoring the merged cell at the top). This will get you the starting row, 2.

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any issues with this.

Comment: Sorry, but this formula does not work. Also, I forgot to mention that in one sheet there could be several entries. I'm adding a new screenshot: https://prnt.sc/nm42pHXpRRkx

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(), 2, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COLUMN(), ROW()-1, 4)))
```

or:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1))
```

Comment: =SUM(INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1)) Works, but only for first entry. I forgot to mention that sheet has several entries. I'm adding a new screenshot: https://prnt.sc/nm42pHXpRRkx